# Android send json to server

Tags: android, json

i write this code for send json to asp.net web page:

```
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // 2. make POST request to the given URL
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            String json = "";
            // 3. build jsonObject
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.accumulate("name", myCountry.name);
            // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
            json = jsonObject.toString();
            // 5. set json to StringEntity
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

            // 6. set httpPost Entity
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(se,"UTF-8");

            // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
```

but in this line :

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(se,"UTF-8");
```

i get this error:

`UrlEncodeFromEntity (java.util.List <? extends org.apache.http.NameValuePair>,String) in UrlEncodedFromEntity cannot be to (org.apache.http.entity.StringEntitym,String)` 
How can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json.toString()));`

instead of

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(se,"UTF-8");
```

Comment: Can i send Arabic character to server with your answer?

Comment: yes you are encoding above as i can see so you can directly use Hardi 's line above

Answer (score 0):

- Just try this line `httpPost.setEntity(se);`

-For arabic characters try **Namevaluepairs**

Example:-

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs1 =  new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", myCountry.name));
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
```

`httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs1));`

Thanks!

Comment: But i want send araboc character to server.in this way i can not sent arabic character to server

Comment: Thanks for pay attention to my problem,please wait to test your solution and  vote up .

Comment: in the BasicNameValuePair i get this android error:import BasicNameValuePair class

Comment: Add **import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;** this line to your import portion of class or Activity